# Python: formatting-print-statements

Tags: python

I am new to python and I am doing one assignment which has one question:

```
Write a function problem4_3(product, cost) so that you can enter the product
and its cost and it will print out nicely. Specifically, allow 25 characters
for the product name and left-justify it in that space; allow 6 characters for 
the cost and right justify it in that space with 2 decimal places. Precede the
cost with a dollar-sign.  There should be no other spaces in the output.
```

And the output should look like:

```
problem4_3("toothbrush",2.6)
toothbrush               $  2.60
```

I tired below function, but their "auto-grader" function didn't accept the answer.

My Function:

```
#%%
def problem4_3(product, cost):

    outputstr = "{0:<25}  {1:>4}  {2:>6.2f}"
    print(outputstr.format(product, "$", cost))

#%%
```

Output:

```
toothbrush                    $  2.60
```

Am I doing something wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why did you give the dollar sign a 4-character-wide field in the output?

Comment: If you compare the outputs you can clearly see that your output is longer.

Comment: Are you certain that the dollar sign should not be next to the amount?

Comment: And why did you put all those spaces between your output fields in the format string when the assignment told you not to do that?

Comment: That is your problem.. it should not have the spaces between fields.

Comment: @user2357112if i didn't give  4-character-wide to dollar sign then the output is added more space

Comment: @user2357112 i removed the extra space in print but still same.

Comment: @SurestTexas i tried as you suggested, but same.

Comment: I tired this string, outputstr = "{0:<25}{1}{2:>6.2f}"  but "auto-grader" again failed to correct my answer.

Comment: That is what we were saying.. however, you are missing the $ sign and the whole `{1:>4}` is not needed.  See my answer below. you need to change the {2:...} to {1:>6.2f}

Comment: `"{0:<25}${1:>6.2f}"`

Comment: @SurestTexas i tired this.
 outputstr = "{0:<25}{1}{2:>6.2f}"
 print(outputstr.format(product,"$",cost))
Still Same :(

Comment: @SurestTexas let me try that.

Comment: That is not right!  you: `"{0:<25}{1}{2:>6.2f}"` .. what I said: `"{0:<25}${1:>6.2f}"`

Comment: If that does not work, then you provided the "wrong" answer in your example, because my answer below provides the "answer" you supplied in your question.

Comment: @SurestTexas Thanks a lot man. It worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This produces the output you say your answer should be:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def problem4_3(product, cost):

    outputstr = "{0:<25}${1:>6.2f}"
    print(outputstr.format(product, cost))


problem4_3("toothbrush", 2.6)
```

produces:

```
/usr/bin/python3.5 /home/surest/github/tests/test.py
toothbrush               $  2.60
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Your "right" answer from above:

```
toothbrush               $  2.60
```

Answer (score -1):

Your output is bigger than the expected output, remember that: "allow 25 characters for the product name". So the product name + white spaces should have 25 characters.

Putting both outputs together we can see the difference:

```
toothbrush               $  2.60
toothbrush                    $  2.60
```